# Android, Preference Screen popup window text color

Tags: android, xml

Does anyone know which parameter in xml theme/styles is responsible for color of texts in PreferenceScreen popup windows?
To ilustrate:

[image: texts which I want to change, background white, color black]

Text color is black, so it was untouched by style properties tried by me. This background is white, but later on I want to change that to something dark and I need to change text's color as well.

PreferenceScreen fragment.

```
public final class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // setting style of the preference screen
    this.getActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_Preference_Screen);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    // I'm setting background color to make cover for activity behind preference screen
    if (view != null) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getActivity(), R.color.colorNavyBlue));
    }
    return view;
}
```

Style which I assign to preference screen. After < item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorJewel< /item> rest is redundant, but I wanted to leave it here, so you can see which one were tried by me.

```
<style name="Theme_Preference_Screen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorJewel</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorVoid</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorFuschia</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorVoid</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorJewel</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="android:keyTextColor">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@color/colorStark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/colorStark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I only succeeded by changing ListPreference (e.g. in R.xml.preference) to com.afollestad.materialdialogs.prefs.MaterialListPreference [from Material-dialogs liberary](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs). Then popups picked up a background color from my theme.